# forwarding SMS messages to email on Iphone 4

Tags: email, iphone, sms

For the holidays I will be in a small town with no cell service. However my job requires that I respond to SMS messages day or night. Is there a way to forward SMS messages to my email address so I will be able to check them (even though my phone hasn't received them yet as it is out of service and shut off)?

Because this wasn't hard enough already, I'm working on an iphone 4.

Thanks in advance for your advice!

Answer (score 1):

This is something only your service provider could do.

If the phone gets no messages, there's very little it can do about forwarding them anywhere else ;)

Though it does make me wonder how you would get the email...

Comment: My guess would be wifi =]

Comment: Which makes me think to point out another possible solution to the problem, most of the American carriers and likely others offer mini-cell sites, that plug into an Ethernet port. If broadband is available it may be possible to just take cell service with you and plug it in. All the carriers have a different marketing name, for example [here is t-mobiles.](https://support.t-mobile.com/community/coverage/personal-cellspot/4g-lte-cellspot)

Comment: I suppose that's a consideration in a place the size of the US. Personally, I've never been anywhere that has data but no phone signal.

Comment: It's possible, I've been places I have no cell signal but wifi is available to me via a broadband connection.  Most of rural America has spotty service away from major roadways.

Comment: My parents live in rural canada, they have high speed internet in the community, but no cell towers.